# Sorting views of a CollectionType based on a position field

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, symfony-2.1

I have a BookEntity (Name,Descript, ...) with a OneToMany relations to TagEntity(name, position)

A tag is linked to only one BookEntity and a BookEntity can have multiple Tags, but can also keep the Tags sorted in an explicit order.

For that I'm using an Drag&Drop javascript plugin in order to set a input field hidden into the TagType I have embed

```
$builder->add('tags','collection', array(
    'type' => new TagType(),
    'allow_add' => true,
    'by_reference' => false,
    'prototype'   => true,
    'allow_delete' => true)
);
```

I can add new Tag using prototype.

but I have existing tags, and I'm going into the Edit page of a BookType.

How can i specify the order of the TagType ?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

referencing [this issue](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/5827) and [this one](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/1421) you can use doctrine's [@OrderBy](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.0.x/reference/annotations-reference.html#orderby) annotation to have the Tags ordered when fetched from database. This will affect the form-collection rendering aswell.

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Tag")
 * @ORM\OrderBy({"position" = "ASC"})
 */
protected $tags;
```

Just as a quick reminder you can order already fetched collections in your controller as described in [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16707694/1832745).

Answer (score 2):

You can sort in your twig view :

```
{% for thing in somethings|sort('ThingIdColum') %}
```