# Sort a doctrine's @OneToMany ArrayCollection

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, one-to-many

My question is close to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16705425/usort-a-doctrine-common-collections-arraycollection), but does not exactly fit with mine.

I've this column in an entity:

```
/**
 * @var ArrayCollection[SubjectTag]
 *
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="SubjectTag", mappedBy="subject")
 * @Assert\Count(max = 10, maxMessage = "You can't create more than 10 tags.")
 * @Assert\Valid()
 */
protected $subjectTags;
```

I want to dynamically order my tags by a position, defined in `SubjectTag.position`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try using the doctrine2 ORM functionality for [Ordering To-Many Associations](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorials/ordered-associations.html#ordering-to-many-associations) like this:

```
/**
 * @var ArrayCollection[SubjectTag]
 *
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="SubjectTag", mappedBy="subject")
 * @ORM\OrderBy({"position" = "ASC"})
 * @Assert\Count(max = 10, maxMessage = "You can't create more than 10 tags.")
 * @Assert\Valid()
 */
protected $subjectTags;
```

Hope this help

Comment: Whooooo so beautiful!

Answer (score 3):

I found a solution, using [@HasLifeCycleCallbacks](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/annotations-reference.html#HasLifecycleCallbacks).

```
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * ...
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks
 */
class Subject
{

    /**
     * @var ArrayCollection[SubjectTag]
     *
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="SubjectTag", mappedBy="subject")
     * @Assert\Count(max = 10, maxMessage = "You can't create more than 10 tags.")
     * @Assert\Valid()
     */
    protected $subjectTags;


    /**
     * @ORM\PostLoad
     */
    public function onPostLoad()
    {
        $tags = $this->subjectTags->toArray();
        usort($tags, function($a, $b) {
            return $a->getPosition() <=> $b->getPosition();
        });
        $this->subjectTags = new ArrayCollection($tags);
    }

}
```

Be careful with performance though, this eagerly loads the collection whatever its fetch mode.

Comment: great trick. But what about `cascade`parameter ? I tried your solution and got an error type `update or delete on table "..." violates foreign key constraint ...`. I think it's because of the new Collection

Comment: Thanks for this, helped with a complex one-to-many sort