# Sort a doctrine's @OneToMany ArrayCollection by field

Tags: symfony, entity

Close question was [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27469222/sort-a-doctrines-onetomany-arraycollection) but I need to more deep sorting:

```
/**
 * @var ArrayCollection[SubjectTag]
 *
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="SubjectTag", mappedBy="subject")
 * @ORM\OrderBy({"position" = "ASC"})
 * @Assert\Valid()
 */
protected $subjectTags;
```

In subjectTag I have:

```
/**
 * @var ArrayCollection[tag]
 *
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Tag", mappedBy="subject")
 * @ORM\OrderBy({"name" = "ASC"})
 * @Assert\Valid()
 */
protected $tags;
```

Now I want to sort by SubjectTag.tags. How can I do that?

EDIT:

Entity1.php:
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Entity2", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=false)
     * @Assert\Valid()
     */
    protected $entity2;

Entity2.php:
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Entity3", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=false)
     * @Assert\Valid()
     */
    protected $entity3;

Entity3.php:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer", nullable=true)
 */
protected $position;
```

And now.. I want have in Entity1 Entity2 sorted by position. How can I do that by default?

Comment: I suggest you to do a custom query in your repository in order to do something more flexible. This annotation allows you to quickly get the result order by a property without adding the subjectTags to your initial query result but you will have a n+1 problem if you want to order by $tags anyway. If you give more details I will be able to show you how to do it in an answer

Comment: @FlorianHermann could u give me example with that custom queries and run it in entity? or maybe I misunderstand something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As explained in my previous comment, you should do a custom query in your repository class corresponding to your base Entity (You didn't give the name of it).

So in your App\Repository\"YourBaseENtityName"Repository class, you do something like this.

```
public function findOrderByTags()
{
    return $this
        ->createQueryBuilder('baseEntityAlias')
        ->addSelect('st')
        ->addSelect('t')
        ->leftJoin('baseEntityAlias.subjectTags', 'st')
        ->leftJoin('st.tags', 't')
        ->orderBy('st.position', 'ASC')
        ->addOrderBy('t.name', 'ASC')
        ->getQuery()
        ->getResult();
}
```

Moreover, I'm not sure about what kind of order you want to perform based on your question. Here the baseEntity->subjectTags will be ordered by their positions and then the baseEntity->subjectTags->tags will be ordered by name.

Now you can call this method from your base entity repository class

Hope it will be helpful for you.

---

EDIT:
Here is a way to introduce a default behavior for your queryBuilder and reuse it.

```
/**
 * In your EntityRepository add a method to init your query builder
 */
public function createDefaultQueryBuilder(string $alias = 'a')
{
    return $this
        ->createQueryBuilder($alias)
        ->addSelect('st')
        ->addSelect('t')
        ->leftJoin('baseEntityAlias.subjectTags', 'st')
        ->leftJoin('st.tags', 't')
        ->orderBy('st.position', 'ASC')
        ->addOrderBy('t.name', 'ASC');
}

/**
 * In this example, I override the default find method. I don't recommend it thought
 */
public function find($id, $lockMode = null, $lockVersion = null)
{
    return $this
        ->createDefaultQueryBuilder()
        ->where('a.id = :id')
        ->setParameter('id', $id)
        ->getQuery()
        ->getOneOrNullResult();
}
```

As you can see, I reuse the createDefaultQueryBuilder method in order to get a default behavior with subjectTags and tags init in the relation and ordered in the right way.

Comment: But now I need to do $entity->findOrderByTags()  to get all tags sorted by position, right?
Can't I do just have in entity sorted?
I mean If I get list of entities I need do foreach, and then replace tags in entity with what I get from findOrderByTags?

Comment: maybe I need only set default orderby for entity? is it possible?

Comment: There is no way to get a default behavior for that. 
I recommend you to do only custom query in your EntityRepository and use a method on it for your default behavior. I will edit this answer to show you how to do it.

Comment: Thanks, but as u mention in answer, overriding default find method is not what You recommended, so what is?:)

Comment: I recommend you to not override the default find but to create your own method named for example findOneWithDetailsById(int $id) and to only call this one. It's your responsability to organize this.