# Symfony query => Error: Expected Literal, got '"'

Tags: php, symfony, query-builder

I have the following query:
(it works fine without the **addSelect('CASE ... END AS HIDDEN loquer')** part
which goals is to add some order into my comments. but with this part the following message from symfony is triggered: **Error: Expected Literal, got '"'**

```
public function myfindArticleandCommentsandScores($article,$language){
    $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('a');
    $qb->leftjoin('a.comments','c')
        ->addSelect('c')
        ->leftJoin('c.scores','s')
        ->addSelect('s')
        ->leftJoin('s.user','u')
        ->addSelect('u')
        ->addSelect('
                CASE 
                    WHEN c.show = "yes" THEN 1  // PROBLEME IS HERE
                    ELSE 2
                END AS HIDDEN show_order  
            ')
        ->where(
                    $qb->expr()->eq('a.id', '?1'),
                    $qb->expr()->orX(
                        $qb->expr()->eq('c.langue', '?2'),
                        $qb->expr()->eq('c.langue', '?3')
                        )
                )
        ->setParameters(array(
                    '1'=> $article,
                    '2'=> $language,
                    '3'=> 'EN',
                ))
        ->orderBy('show_order', 'ASC')
        ->addOrderBy('c.scorenote', 'DESC');

    return $qb->getQuery()
                ->getResult();
}
```

I tried to replace "yes" with 'yes' but then I got the following message: **FatalErrorException: Parse: syntax error, unexpected 'oui' (T_STRING)**

Comment: 'Yes' is correct but than use " as string delimiter

Answer (score 2):

Use setParameter to replace a placeholder with a string or use 
 `"xyz='yes'"`

Now what the code should looks like (one possible way):

```
public function myfindArticleandCommentsandScores($article,$language){
    $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('a');
    $qb->leftjoin('a.comments','c')
        ->addSelect('c')
        ->leftJoin('c.scores','s')
        ->addSelect('s')
        ->leftJoin('s.user','u')
        ->addSelect('u')
        ->addSelect('
                CASE 
                    WHEN c.show = \'yes\' THEN 1  // PROBLEME IS HERE
                    ELSE 2
                END AS HIDDEN show_order  
            ')
        ->where(
                    $qb->expr()->eq('a.id', '?1'),
                    $qb->expr()->orX(
                        $qb->expr()->eq('c.langue', '?2'),
                        $qb->expr()->eq('c.langue', '?3')
                        )
                )
        ->setParameters(array(
                    '1'=> $article,
                    '2'=> $language,
                    '3'=> 'EN',
                ))
        ->orderBy('show_order', 'ASC')
        ->addOrderBy('c.scorenote', 'DESC');

    return $qb->getQuery()
                ->getResult();
}
```

Comment: Yep wait some minutes.

Answer (score 1):

String delimiters in DQL should be avoided where possible.

```
->addSelect('
    CASE 
        WHEN c.show = :show THEN 1
        ELSE 2
    END AS HIDDEN show_order  
')
->setParameter('show', 'yes')
```

Answer (score 0):

I added a parameter just like this:

```
->addSelect('
    CASE 
           WHEN t.loquage = :show_first THEN 1
           ELSE 2
    END AS HIDDEN loquer  
            ')
->setParameters(array(
        'show_first'=> 'oui',
```

thanks to Qoop who helped me.