# Add sort to child one-to-many filter in Symfony

Tags: php, symfony, oop, doctrine-orm

I have made an relation between an Product en its child images. An normal one-to-many association.

With the following code i get the child images in an object:

```
$product->getImages();
```

The I want to walk through the images to modify something, I do this with:

```
foreach ($product->getImages() as $Image) {
            // do something
        }
```

Only the images have an field called seq what is an number that represents the order of the images. How can I order the object related to the seq number?

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["usort" a Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16705425/usort-a-doctrine-common-collections-arraycollection)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use annotation @orderBy for this. Please use something like

```
<?php
/** @Entity **/
class Product
{
    /**
     * @OneToMany(targetEntity="Image")
     * @OrderBy({"seq" = "ASC"})
     **/
    private $images;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could add the annotation on the Doctrine relation (but this would effect on all access you make to the collection and you can't implement another sorting methods) **or** you can implement a custom filter in the Product Entity itself using the **Doctrine Criteria** (See some examples [here](https://gist.github.com/Ocramius/3368674)).

As Example:

```
class Product
{
    /**
     * @OneToMany(targetEntity="Image")
     **/
    private $images;

public function __construct()
{
    $this->images = new ArrayCollection();
}

public function getSortedImages()
{
    $expr = Criteria::expr();

    $criteria = Criteria::create()
        ->where($expr->neq('seq', null)) // Analog to IS NOT NULL
        ->orderBy(array('seq'=>'DESC'));

    return $this->images->matching($criteria);
}

}
```

Hope this help

For simple scenario the solutions posted by @Liju P M is good

Answer (score 0):

In symfony 3.4 you should make it

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Image")
 * @ORM\OrderBy({"seq" = "ASC"})
 **/
```

and don't forget the use statment

```
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
```