# Symfony 3 - Doctrine 2 - orderBy on oneToMany relation does not work

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, orm, mapping

I have a very simple `oneToMany`/`manyToOne` relation between two entities:

One `Workflow` holds many `States`:

```
MyBundle\Entity\Workflow:
  type: entity
  id:
    id:
      type: integer
      generator: {strategy: AUTO}
  oneToMany:
    states:
      targetEntity: MyBundle\Entity\State
      mappedBy: workflow
      orderBy:
        stateOrder: ASC
      cascade: [all]
      orphanRemoval: true
      fetch: EAGER
  ...
```

Many `States` holding one `Workflow`:

```
MyBundle\Entity\State:
  type: entity
  id:
    id:
      type: integer
      generator: {strategy: AUTO}
  manyToOne:
    workflow:
      targetEntity: MyBundle\Entity\Workflow
      inversedBy: states
      cascade: [persist, merge, refresh]
  ...
  fields:
    stateOrder:
      type: smallint
```

But neither `orderBy: ASC` nor `orderBy: DESC` orders the states. I ran `php bin/console doctrine:schema:update --force --complete --dump-sql`, cleared the cache and restarted apache when changing the option.

I also tried [doctrines official way](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/tutorials/ordered-associations.html) of adding the `orderBy` option: `orderBy: {'stateOrder': 'DESC'}` / `orderBy: {'stateOrder': 'ASC'}` with same results...

---

Here is the query which ran when rendering a form:

```
SELECT 
  t0.id AS id_1, 
  t0.name AS name_2, 
  t0.project_id AS project_id_3, 
  t4.id AS id_5, 
  t4.stateOrder AS stateOrder_6, 
  t4.workflow_id AS workflow_id_7, 
  t8.id AS id_9, 
  t8.keyWord AS keyWord_10, 
  t8.action AS action_11, 
  t8.workflow_id AS workflow_id_12, 
  t8.from_id AS from_id_13, 
  t8.to_id AS to_id_14, 
  t0.initialState_id AS initialState_id_15 
FROM 
  workflow_Workflow t0 
  LEFT JOIN workflow_State t4 ON t4.workflow_id = t0.id 
  LEFT JOIN workflow_Transition t8 ON t8.workflow_id = t0.id 
WHERE 
  t0.id = '10';
```

So order by is not part of the query...

Any suggestions why this doesn´t work?

Comment: Are you fetching those entities using a special query? If so: Is the `State` entity fetch-joined?

Comment: Also: [DDC-3448](https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2/issues/4256) is probably related.

Comment: No, the entities get loaded automatically by Symfonys `ParamConverter`... But I found the problem on [github](https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2/issues/4256): `orderBy` does not work on `EAGER`!. Thanks anyway... (You where faster founding the issue! thx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a known [open issue](https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2/issues/4256) that `orderBy` does not work in combination with `fetch: EAGER`. So either deleting `fetch: EAGER` or [sorting the doctrine collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16705425/usort-a-doctrine-common-collections-arraycollection) solves the problem.